# Как для border dashed задать градиент?

Tags: html, css

[image: вот так должен быть бордер]

```css
.Rectangle-5 {
 margin: 51px 0px 0px 35px;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 370px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
/*  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;*/
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4fc3f7, #ab5ca4 49%, #ff512f);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Rectangle-5"></div>
```

Есть такой квадрат.но как сделать его рамку dotted или dashed при том чтобы цвета не менялись?

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем три свойства `background-image`, `background-origin`, `background-clip`. С цветами дальше просто поиграться, чтобы получить что хочется

```css
.Rectangle-5 {
 margin: 51px 0px 0px 35px;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 370px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(blue, magenta);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="Rectangle-5"></div>
```

Comment: @Kniha m вы меня не поняли я загрузил изображение как должно выглядеть border.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.Rectangle-5 {
  margin: 51px 0px 0px 35px;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 370px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4fc3f7, #ab5ca4 49%, #ff512f);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.Rectangle-5:after {
  top:-1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
    
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, white 0),
  linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, white 0),
  linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, white 0),
  linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, white 0);
  background-size: 5px 1px, 5px 1px, 1px 5px, 1px 5px;
  background-position: top, bottom, left, right;
  background-repeat: repeat-x,repeat-x,repeat-y,repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="Rectangle-5"></div>
```

Цвет **white** в `background-image` надо заменить на цвет фона, который необходим. Редактировать ширину пунктирных полосок можно с помощью `background-size`.

Comment: вы меня не поняли я загрузил изображение как должно выглядеть border.